# Why do Rust programs use so much more memory than the C, Haskell and OCaml versions?

Tags: rust

I looked at how much RAM was used by Rust programs (`RES` column from `top` command) and I wonder why they use so much memory.

Here is an example:

```
use std::io;

fn main() {
    println!("What's your name?");
    let mut input = String::new();
    io::stdin().read_line(&mut input).unwrap();
    println!("Hello {}!", input);
}
```

I saw that 6 MB of memory was used before I input something.

Here is how I compiled and executed the program:

```
cargo build --release
./target/release/main
```

The equivalent C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("What's your name?\n");
    char input[100] = {0};
    scanf("%s", input);
    printf("Hello %s!\n", input);
    return 0;
}
```

only uses 0.6 MB. In this case, the Rust program uses 10 times more memory. In other cases, I saw that the Rust program uses 5 times more memory.

I also tested with other languages to compare.

The OCaml version:

```
let () =
    print_endline "What's your name?";
    let line = read_line () in
    print_string "Hello ";
    print_endline line
```

uses 1 MB.

The Haskell version:

```
main = do
    putStrLn "What's your name?"
    name <- getLine
    putStrLn ("Hello " ++ name ++ "!")
```

uses 3 MB.

The Python version:

```
print("What's your name?")
name = input()
print("Hello", name, "!")
```

uses 7 MB, almost the same as the Rust version!

### Update

I'm running Linux (ArchLinux) with Rust 1.3 (I also tried the nightly with similar results).

### Update 2

Here is more data from the `htop` command:

```
VIRT    RES     SHR     MEM%    Command
15572   2936    804     0.1     ocaml
21728   2732    2528    0.1     haskell
22540   7480    4308    0.2     python
4056    668     600     0.0     c
24180   6164    1928    0.2     rust
```

### Update 3

I did more tests with `massif` to see the memory usage.

For every program, I ran `massif` twice, as following:

```
valgrind --tool=massif --time-unit=B ./program
valgrind --tool=massif  --pages-as-heap=yes --time-unit=B ./program
```

Here are the results with all the programs (as shown by `ms_print`):

**C versions:**

https://framabin.org/?dd243f8ec99155bc#Af5cPrcHnz3DsWiOStfwgW8Qq6BTVhogz/46L+sMuSs=

https://framabin.org/?261b9366c3749469#1ztDBkgVly9CanrrWWrJdh3yBFL5PEIW3OI5OLnze/Q=

**Rust versions:**

https://framabin.org/?0f1bac1c750e97bf#AXwlFYYPHeazq9LfsTOpRBaUTTkb1NfN9ExPorDJud0=

https://framabin.org/?c24b21b01af36782#OLFWdwLjVG2t7eoLqLFhe0Pp8Q8pA2S/oq4jdRRWPzI=

**OCaml versions:**

https://framabin.org/?060f05bea318109c#/OJQ8reHCU3CzzJ5NCOCLOYJQFnA1VgxqAIVjgQWX9I=

https://framabin.org/?8ff1ffb6d03cb37a#GN8bq3Wrm6tNWaINIhMAr4ieltLtOPjuZ4Ynof9bV4w=

**Haskell versions:**

https://framabin.org/?b204bd978b8c1fd8#DyQH862AM8NEPTKlzEcZgoapPaZLdlF9W3dRn47K5yU=

https://framabin.org/?ac1aa89fcaeb782c#TQ+uAiqerjHuuEEIhehVitjm63nc3wu5wfivAeBH5uI=

**Python versions:**

https://framabin.org/?197e8b90df5373ec#aOi0+tEj32Na5jW66Kl97q2lsjSZ2x7Cwl/pOt0lYIM=

https://framabin.org/?397efa22484e3992#1ylOrmjKaA9Hg7gw7H7rKGM0MyxuvKwPNN1J/jLEMrk=

Summary (ram usage):

```
|------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|
|            |     C    | Haskell  |   OCaml  |   Rust   |  Python  |
|------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|
| First run  |    1 B   | 63.12 KB | 5.993 MB |   816 B  | 1.321 MB |
|------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|
| Second run | 6.031 MB | 24.20 MB | 17.14 MB | 25.60 MB | 27.43 MB |
|------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|
```

The first run is without the `--pages-as-heap=yes` parameter.

I also ran `massif` with the `--stacks=yes` option for C and Rust.

**C version:**

https://framabin.org/?b3009d198ccfdee1#HxR6LPPAzt15K+wIFdaqlfSJjBrJvhV2ZHWdElg3ezc=

(3.141 KB)

**Rust version:**

https://framabin.org/?b446d8d76c279007#tHnGiOnRstTA2krhz6cgfvTjI+FclcZS3rqyZvquWdQ=

(8.602 KB)

What does explain such a huge difference between heap block allocation and page allocation in Rust?

Comment: Until you reach the range of GB, what is the problem (assuming not running on embedded platform)? Did you test larger and larger programs and found that it still scales the same? Or is there some "minimum" due to runtime environment and it scales reasonably after that?

Comment: On OS X, using Rust 1.3, your Rust program uses 660K according to top. You probably should [edit] your question to include these details.

Comment: @crashmstr It would still be surprising (to me) if the fixed overhead for the runtime would be larger for rust than e.g. Haskell.

Comment: @Shepmaster I updated my question. How does the Rust version compare to the C version on your computer?

Comment: @antoyo: Why not show the output of your top command (with headings); on my system I see "VIRT", "RES" and "SHR" and those have different meanings; it's unclear from your description which one you are referring to, which in turns prevents any kind of meaningful answer.

Comment: Of course, they aren't exactly the same. At the moment, the C version is waiting to be a buffer overrun exploit which I assume the Rust one isn't. Even if you fix that issue (by specifying a width), you'll still get markedly different behaviour if your name is 10000 characters long.

Comment: Can confirm that rust has a somewhat high initial memory requirement for a compiled language with a supposedly zero-sized runtime. For an example of the measurement see the http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u64q/rust.html – they show very similar memory consumption patterns. Note that static linking cannot explain the difference e.g. to C. Perhaps it is due to jemalloc settings on linux?

Comment: @MatthieuM. I edited my answer to include the column I checked in the `top` command. If needed, I will include the full lines.

Comment: @antoyo: I am no power user of top, however I believe that `RES` is the total memory used by the program (physically) and `SHR` is the part of the total memory that is shared with other processes (in general, all the code and read-only values is shared). So it would be interesting to see `SHR` too, to know what's the proportion of shared/private memory consumption in the Rust process, which gives us the proportion of "code" vs "mutable globals + stack + heap". A statically compiled binary has a larger code footprint, for example, but this is fixed overhead (for a given binary).

Comment: @MatthieuM. Wouldn't that imply that the statically compiled binary be as large as the memory it consumes initially?

Comment: @llogiq: not quite, the RES will initially contain (on top of SHR) space for mutable globals and the beginning of the stack. Of course, Linux muddy the waters by (1) using CoW of the memory pages (so that if you fork your process, you initially inherit the mutable globals pages) and (2) lazily mapping the pages (so that you only have a couple pages of memory for the stack instead of the whole 8MB you have requested, for example). But otherwise, as far as I know, RES > SHR. Of course, take it with a grain of salt, I am no power user of top...

Comment: @MatthieuM. Yes, but the memory consumption is higher than the sum of the 1MB stack (which is the default on Linux, AFAIK) plus the source. Of course, jemalloc may ask the system for more memory for its arenas.

Comment: @all I added more detailed profiling info in my question. Does anybody know why the Rust version uses more memory with this data?

Comment: @Shepmaster It seems platform-specific. I've just tried on FreeBSD and the ram usage of this rust program is similar to C++. Perhaps having jemalloc as the system allocator has something to do with this result. Do you know if OS X also use jemalloc as the system allocator?

Comment: Framabin (PrivateBin)
This service no longer exists here…

Could you please reupload pastes?

Answer (score 28):

Because the standard library is statically linked.

You can overcome this by compiling with the `-C prefer-dynamic` option.

As to the reason behind having the standard library statically linked: it increases executable portability (ie: no need for the standard library to be installed in target system).

Comment: With this option, there are some changes, but it still use more RAM than the Haskell and OCaml versions.  [The only ways that were found to reduce the RAM usage was to use the system allocator or the `no_std` feature](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/why-do-rust-programs-use-more-memory-than-the-c-haskell-and-ocaml-versions/3224), but it does not explain why Rust use more RAM by default.

Comment: There might also be a lot of inlining

Comment: The standard library wouldn't be faulted in for such a simple program. jemalloc is a more likely explanation.

Comment: Back then, Windows executables were bigger, too, and rust for Windows didn't come with jemalloc at the time. (I talk in past because I haven't been using rust for quite some time now; jemalloc may still not used in Rust for windows)

Comment: And why does stdlib is linked in full? if only console io is in use?

Comment: I don't remember if I meant to imply it was linked in full - the important thing was the link was static itself, which meant whatever code that was linked got loaded with the rest of the executable.
It's been a long time and I barely recall anything about the topic. In fact, it's likely my answer is outdated - toying a bit I couldn't find the -C flag; the executable for the example is tiny (144KB); and the executable in the example doesn't even use half a MB of RAM!

Answer (score 10):

Since this question is on top results from google, I would like to give an update for anybody looking at this in 2022. I ran the exact same program and measured rust RSS from htop. It shows 924KB. That is 0.92MB. Apparently rust has improved a lot in these years.

Answer (score 0):

[This article](https://lifthrasiir.github.io/rustlog/why-is-a-rust-executable-large.html) has a very good discussion  of the topic. Some of the largest and most common culprits are cargo's default to debug builds (not relevant in your case) and statically including libraries by default.